# adobe edge: how to make triggered photo animation?

Tags: triggers, adobe-edge

i recreating a website in edge that i originally created in flash.
 
http://thepearlnj.com/
 
i need help with how to make the 3 radial buttons on the left under the Pearl logo (on the home page) work in edge. I would like to keep the way they animate/slide from photo to photo
 
i would really appreciate it if someone could set up a simple edge document with 3 boxes that represent photos & 3 buttons & upload it. That way i can look at the code in the buttons & timeline & figure out how it works.
 
or if it's really simple, please let me know which code i need to use on the buttons to create the same effect. (I think the 3 photos need to be set up as a symbol, with triggers on the timeline)
 
thank you all in advance for your help!
 
-sharon

Answer (score -1):

See the following project example...

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzrivIceUbSWVWp2S1FuLTZRR00/edit?usp=sharing

I setup 3 buttons as symbols with hover states. Each has a click function. I used JQUERY to animate the IMAGEHOLDER and MASK to only make one image visible at a time.

Enjoy!

Adam

Comment: Paste the code here, of if it's to much, try sharing it with something other than a Gdrive request-access doc

Comment: sorry about that Nunser, I forgot to make the link public. please remove the -1 when you have a chance. A lot of work went into this answer, I appreciate your help.

Comment: The file from your link not exist